# Which Datatype in MYSQL do I use to store only numbers 1 to 60 inside a data table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created one table and I want to store numbers from 1 to 60 numbers only inside the field.

What should I put in the datatype of the table field? Should I use `TINYINT (4)` datatype?

Comment: 60 digits is an awfully big number. (your question conflicts with the title)

Comment: Do you want to store 1 to 60 _digits_, or values from 1 to 60?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i lied at this time, i read title and make an answer.

Comment: Store any number from 1 to 60.

Comment: What do you mean by best - least storage space? limit values to a max of 60?

Comment: Also, if you're using MySQL 8.0.16+, you can (and should here) use check constraints for this limitation: `CHECK (my_field >= 0 AND my_field <= 60`

Answer (score 2):

"Best" data type is open to interpretation.  Here are three options:

```
numeric(2, 0)
varchar(2)
tinyint(2)
```

These have different sizes, but that doesn't make them "best" -- except under certain circumstances where storage space is a primary concern.  I am guessing that your "numbers" are not really numbers, but are codes of some sort that vary from 1 to 60.

If these are referencing a reference table, then `tinyint` makes sense as the key, because keys are often numbers.  However, I often use `int` for such keys.  The extra three bytes usually have little impact on performance.

If the code is zero-padded (so `'01'` rather than `'1'`), then `char(2)` is the appropriate type.  It might take more space, but it accurately represents the value.

If these are indeed numbers -- like addition or multiplication is defined -- then `tinyint` is definitely the most appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `TINYINT` is the best option its from -128 to 127!

**Documentation Link:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html